# How to get the first paragraph bold in the php?

Tags: php, nl2br

I am entering text in the database in two paragraphs

```
first paragraph
second paragraph
```

I am storing them in my database and when I am displaying them on the frontend using `nl2br` it is getting displayed perfectly.

I want the my first paragraph to be bold and the second paragraph should be normal.

I tried using `strpos` to find the location of the `<br>` tag after `nl2br` to chop off the first paragraph but I am not succeeding.

the failed code is

```
echo strpos(nl2br($row['article']), "<br>");
```

but i am not getting the position of the `<br>` tag

I got the correct answer from eddie, he deleted it but i am updating the answer here

```
$str='first paragraph
      second paragraph';
foreach(explode("\n",) as $key => $val) { 
if($key == 0){
echo'<b>'; 
}     
echo $val;
echo'<br>';
if($key == 0){ 
echo '</b>';
}
}
```

Comment: Have code, will travel.

Comment: Why not just use CSS?

Comment: `<p><b>first paragraph</b></p><p>second paragraph</p>`, *there*.

Comment: @Fred-ii-very funny. I have updated the code

Comment: I like to think that I have a sense of humour ;-)

Comment: @j08691 because data is coming from database

Comment: So? You can still use CSS selectors to target the first paragraph only.

Comment: Do you want the bold tags to also be inserted into DB? If not and as already stated, you can use CSS selectors to target the first paragraph only. If it's to go into DB, have you tried Eddie's answer below?

Comment: eddies answer worked perfectly

Comment: unfortunately he deleted it, but i will update that in my question

Comment: @UglyEddie You should undelete your answer. OP says it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t use [`nl2br`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) for the type of results you are looking for. Just split the string into an array using a regex rule with [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and then act on the first item in the array. Here is test code:

```
// Set the test data.
$test_data = <<<EOT
first paragraph
second paragraph
EOT;

// Split the test data into an array of lines.
$line_array = preg_split('/(\r?\n){1,2}/', $test_data);

// Roll through the line array & act on the first line.
$final_text = '';
foreach ($line_array as $line_key => $line_value) {
  if ($line_key == 0) {
    $line_value = "<b>" . $line_value . "</b>";
  }
  $final_text .= $line_value . "<br />\n";
}

// Dump the line array for debugging.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($line_array);
echo '</pre>';

// Echo the final text.
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlentities($final_text);
echo '</pre>';

die();
```

The output from the dump of the line array would be this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => first paragraph
    [1] => second paragraph
)
```

And the test output using [`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to show what was done HTML-wise:

```
<b>first paragraph</b><br />
second paragraph<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$first_line = explode(PHP_EOL, $str)[0];
$new_str = str_replace($first_line,'<b>'.$first_line.'</b>',nl2br($str));
```